# Github actions share data between different worflow runs

Tags: github-actions

How can I share data e.g. some id to a different worklow run which will be run at a later time?

I tried using artifacts but they seem to work only within same workflow run between jobs

Answer (score 2):

An official action `actions/download-artifact` doesn't support sharing artifacts between pipeline but you can use this one [`dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2`](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact)

```yaml
- name: Download artifact
  uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
  with:
    # Optional, GitHub token
    github_token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
    # Required, workflow file name or ID
    workflow: workflow_name.yml
    # Optional, will get head commit SHA
    pr: ${{github.event.pull_request.number}}
    # Optional, no need to specify if PR is
    commit: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.sha}}
    # Optional, will use the branch
    branch: master
    # Optional, will use specified workflow run
    run_id: 1122334455
    # Optional, uploaded artifact name,
    # will download all artifacts if not specified
    # and extract them in respective subdirectories
    # https://github.com/actions/download-artifact#download-all-artifacts
    name: artifact_name
    # Optional, directory where to extract artifact
    path: extract_here
    # Optional, defaults to current repo
    repo: ${{github.repository}}
```